# Passing the destination memory address as a uint32_t to memcpy throws warning

Tags: c, pointers, memcpy

I am currently writing a kernel which involves a lot of arithmetic on memory addresses and am getting the following infamous warning on memcpy:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
   memcpy(dest, &bf, 16*sizeof(uint32_t));
```

The example of where the warning is thrown is when I do the following

```
uint32_t bf[16];

uint32_t shmem = (uint32_t)&tos_shared;
uint32_t dest = shmem - 16*sizeof(uint32_t);
memcpy(dest, &bf, 16*sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Where `&tos_shared (0x700347a8)` is the top of stack memory address. I cast it to a `uint32_t (1879263144)` so I can do the arithmetic and get my desired destination address, `dest (1879262952)`.

How can I convert `dest` to a pointer but retain the destination address so memcpy doesn't complain and bf is put in the same place? It's worth mentioning this code functions fine...

Comment: The message says, *"makes pointer from integer without a **cast**"* So the answer is to **cast** it: `memcpy((void *)dest, ...`

Comment: ...Or just use pointer arithmetic. Well, in case some conditions (like having the result to point inside the same object) apply.

Comment: You are assuming--perhaps correctly, perhaps not--that a memory address fits into 32 bits. That's certainly not true for many popular architectures now. Interesting that you aren't assuming that sizeof(uint32_t) is 4, which is true by definition. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast back to a pointer type in order to call `memcpy` (either `char *` or `void *` will work; `void *` is more idiomatic here).  You also need to do the manual pointer arithmetic using `uintptr_t` rather than `uint32_t`.

```
uint32_t bf[16];

uintptr_t shmem = (uintptr_t)&tos_shared;
uintptr_t dest = shmem - 16*sizeof(uint32_t);
memcpy((void *)dest, &bf, 16*sizeof(uint32_t));
```

This code is not guaranteed to work universally.  However, it is implementation-defined whether it works, and since you are writing a kernel, you *are* (part of) the implementation, so you get to decide that yes, the layout of physical RAM will always be such that it does work.

Depending on your ABI, `uint32_t` and `uintptr_t` may or may not be the same fundamental type, but you should still use `uintptr_t` even if they are, because that's more self-documenting and will make it easier to go 64-bit in the future (assuming that's something you might want).

Answer (score 3):

You would get the right result by using a `char*` to `&tos_shared`. You can also use `sizeof bf` to simplify a bit.

```
uint32_t bf[16];

char* shmem = (char*)&tos_shared;
void* dest = shmem - sizeof bf; // sizeof bf == sizeof(uint32_t) * 16
memcpy(dest, &bf, sizeof bf);
```

If you ever do need to store a pointer in an integral type (which you should avoid anyway), the correct type to use is `uintptr_t`

Comment: Nice simplification suggestions! Although I believe if I were to do the uint32_t arithmetic directly in the `dest` assignment here I'd get a warning?

Comment: @bluey31 there's no integer arithmetic here, it's all pointers, so no warning. The only thing I'm not sure about is whether or not it's safer to do `shmem - sizeof bf` at all since it's taking a pointer out of bounds, but this is a weird case to start since the original pointer is a constant. I think you're a little outside the language's specifications here.

Comment: @bluey31 let me put it this way, the expression `shmem - N` in this case says "give me a pointer N bytes before shmem"

Comment: Sure, makes sense :)

Comment: @bluey31 I'm not really sure why you want to be doing integer arithmetic at all if what you are dealing with are memory addresses